# Replacing duplicate words but leaving the middle word using regex with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've imported some a table into pd.dataframe. Within the dataframe there's a column with company names, and I would like to clean it up by removing duplicate words.

For example:

1. "Benz-Benz" => "Benz"
2. "Tesla 123-Tesla 123" => "Tesla 123"
3. "Apple Store Inc-Apple Store In" => "Apple Store Inc"

so far, I figured out how to use regex to deal with the first 2 cases. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the third case.

Here's my code for the third case:

```
df_comp['comp_no_duplicate'] = df_comp['comp_name'].str \
                    .replace(r'(^\b[A-Z]{1,}.*\b)(.*)-{1}\b\1\b', r'\1\2')
```

With this code, I get the result for the third case to be:
"Apple Store Inc-Apple Store In" => "Apple Store IncIn"

How do I write the regex for this case?

Comment: Is it always separated by a `-`? If so a simple `x.split('-')[0]` would be enough...

Comment: `df_comp['comp_no_duplicate'] = df_comp['comp_name'].str.replace(r'^(.*)-\1$', r'\1', regex=True)`. Note `Apple Store Inc-Apple Store In` has no repetition of the string before `-`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, the company names with duplicates in them are always separated by a "-", but there are also other company names without duplicates that also have "-" in their names.

Comment: So, does the `r'^(.*)-\1$'` work?

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding this many (potential) rules can be cumbersome. Maybe you can approach this a little different. You don't want duplicate terms. So why not just filter out terms that occur more than once?

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on what you need. You can keep the first occurrence, the last, and you can go for speed (which will sacrifice the order of the terms) or insist on maintaining the order. Here are some suggestions for implementation:

```py
import re
import pandas

from typing import List


# Your data
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        {"text": "Benz-Benz"},
        {"text": "Tesla 123-Tesla 123"},
        {"text": "Apple Store Inc-Apple Store In"},
    ]
)


def unordered_deduplicate(text: str) -> str:
    """Take a string and remove duplicate terms, without preserving
    the order of the terms.

    Args:
        text (str): The input text

    Returns:
        str: The cleaned output
    """
    return " ".join(set(re.split(r"\s|-", text)))


def ordered_deduplicate(text: str) -> str:
    """Take a string and remove duplicate terms, only keeping the
    first occurence of a term.

    Args:
        text (str): The input string

    Returns:
        str: The cleaned output
    """

    # Make a list of all the terms
    unique_terms_count = {term: 0 for term in set(re.split(r"\s|-", text))}

    # Loop the terms
    cleaned: List[str] = []
    for term in re.split(r"\s|-", text):

        # Only keep them in the cleaned list if they haven't been seen before
        if unique_terms_count[term] == 0:
            cleaned.append(term)
            unique_terms_count[term] += 1

    return " ".join(cleaned)


# Create clean text columns in different ways
df["unordered_text"] = df["text"].apply(unordered_deduplicate)
df["ordered_text"] = df["text"].apply(ordered_deduplicate)

print(df)
```